# Can't compile custom plugin

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi! I'm doing the Gazebo tutorial on making your own plugin. I'm currently on the [Control plugin part](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i5), but when I try running make (after `cmake ..`) I get the following error:

```
~/Developer/Gazebo/velodyne_plugin/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target velodyne_plugin
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/velodyne_plugin.dir/velodyne_plugin.cc.o
/home/martint/Developer/Gazebo/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::VelodynePlugin::Load(gazebo::physics::ModelPtr, sdf::ElementPtr)’:
/home/martint/Developer/Gazebo/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:23:8: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class gazebo::physics::Model’
  _model->GetName() << "]\n";
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/common/Plugin.hh:49:0,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/common/common.hh:34,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/gazebo_core.hh:19,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/gazebo.hh:20,
                 from /home/martint/Developer/Gazebo/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:4:
/usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/physics/PhysicsTypes.hh:37:11: note: forward declaration of ‘class gazebo::physics::Model’
     class Model;
           ^
```

My code and folder structure is exactly as in the tutorial, and I've installed Gazebo using `apt install gazebo7`. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04. Gazebo runs fine otherwise, and I've been able to follow several tutorials without errors. Thankful for any help :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14078/can%27t-compile-custom-plugin/) by [hassanbot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2754/hassanbot/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

See [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13810/the-control-plugin-tutorials-example-code-is-giving-me-errors/) question. The problem can be solved by adding the following include to your cc file:

`#include <gazebo/physics/Model.hh>`

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hassanbot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2754/hassanbot/) on 2016-08-09**:
Thanks, works like a charm :)